# How to create a tree structure in Knockout using a Knockout template?

Tags: javascript, database, knockout.js, knockout-2.0, knockout-templating

I am working with `Knockout` support and now creating tree structured `UI` component. Here i will create the elements dynamically and there i want to bind the data to newly created elements. 
Please check with the below code

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>

<script type="text/html" id="tree">
   <li menuid="data bind with attr binding">
      <span>&nbsp;</span>
      <span><a href="#" name="endnode"></span>
      <ul data-bind="template: { name: 'tree', foreach: childNodes }">
     </ul>
   </li>
```

below is my script

```
 var viewModel = {
 Mytree: ko.observable({
childNodes: [
  {
    id: 1,name:"node1",
    childNodes: [ {id: 2, name:"node2", childNodes: [{id: 3,name:"node3", childNodes: [] }] } ]
  },
  {
    id: 4,name:"node4",
    childNodes: [ {id: 5,name:"node5", childNodes: [] } ]
   }
 ]
  })
};

ko.applyBindings(new viewModel.Mytree());
```

Now i want to append the `bindable` node names to to tree like below:

```
<span><a href="#" name="endnode" data-bind:"text:childNodes.name"/></span>
```

`<ul data-bind="template: { name: 'tree', foreach: childNodes }">`

Can you please any one suggest me to achieve this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you pass it the view model (you can use the $root syntax for this) you can just use "name" in the binding.  The context will change as it goes down the tree ... there's a couple of other bits wrong - for one it's data-bind= (equals, not colon)

Try this template ...

```
      <script type="text/html" id="tree">
         <li menuid="data bind with attr binding">
            <span>&nbsp;</span>
            <a href="#" data-bind="text: name"></a>
            <ul data-bind="template: { name: 'tree', foreach: childNodes }" />
         </li>
     </script>
```

and use this to kick things off (note $root)

```
  <ul data-bind="template: { name: 'tree', data: $root }" />
```

this will give you ...

[image]